# No parameterless constructor defined for this object(Asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm using asp.net mvc for a very basic websitre that is for shopping books.
anyway, I've got an error with this title

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

and this is my model :

```cs
public class BookGenre
    {
        public BookGenre()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int GenreID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Genre Title")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your {0}")]
        public string GenreTitle { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Book> Book { get; set; }
    }
```

so the problem is my model 'Has a parameterless constructor'

Additional information >>

this is where i'm using my model:

```cs
public class PageController : Controller
    {
        private BooksContext db = new BooksContext();
        private IBookGenreRepository bookGenreRepository;

        public PageController(BooksContext context)
        {
            bookGenreRepository = new BookGenreRepository(db);
        }

        public ActionResult HeaderGenres()
        {
            return PartialView(bookGenreRepository.GetAllGenres());
        }
    }
```

and this is "BookGenreRepository" where 'GetAllGenres' implemented.

```cs
public class BookGenreRepository : IBookGenreRepository
    {
        BooksContext db;

        public BookGenreRepository(BooksContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BookGenre> GetAllGenres()
        {
            return db.BookGenres;
        }

        public BookGenre GetGenreByID(int genreId)
        {
            return db.BookGenres.Find(genreId);
        }

        public IEnumerable<BookGenre> GetGenresByFilter(string filterBy)
        {
            return db.BookGenres.Where(g => g.GenreTitle.Contains(filterBy));
        }

        public bool AddGenre(BookGenre bookGenre)
        {
            try
            {
                db.BookGenres.Add(bookGenre);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool EditGenre(BookGenre bookGenre)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Entry(bookGenre).State = EntityState.Modified;
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool DeleteGenre(BookGenre bookGenre)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Entry(bookGenre).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool DeleteGenreByID(int genreId)
        {
            var genre = GetGenreByID(genreId);

            try
            {
                DeleteGenre(genre);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Error Picture :
[this is Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcORd.jpg)

please someone help me

if you need more information about my code please tell me to edit question

Comment: How is `GetAllGenres` implemented?

Comment: Are the dependencies registered in the DI framework?

Comment: Try removing `BooksContext context` from the controller constructor. It is not used anyway

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't know why i put 'context' into the constructor. thanks